# onMouseOver Jquery news widget

Tags: jquery

I have  revised a jquery box :

```
http://designer-depot.com/manset/test.html
```

In `<ol></ol>` everything work perfect. But I want to on mouseover `<h2>` and abstract news for headline1,2,3 changing. 
How can I do this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Try to explain the problem in more detail.

Comment: Please revisit the link. I have revised it 
I want to :
-when hovering on image1 link:
  HeadLine2,HeadLine3 and  abstract news for headline2 be hidden!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the text inside the event handler, for example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#headlines ol li").mouseover(function(){
        $("#headlines ol li").removeClass("current");
        $(this).toggleClass("current");
        $("h2", this).text("Whatever you want it to say");
    });
});
```

You should also use an `if()` to see what link is hovered, and then change the text depending on the link. You can use the same principle to change the description.